# Implicit conversion to string instead of getting "Object ID #.."

Tags: php, string, object, casting, tostring

I've moved to a new webhost were we have php 5.1 instead of 5.2 that I've been using until now. I still haven't figured out if it's a php version or configuration issue.

Right now most (or all) of the classes that have __toString functions convert to "Object ID #" (like in php4) but before they all returned the correct values.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you be a bit more explicit with the issue you're having?  Greater detail on what happened before (with 5.2) and what's happening now (with 5.1)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently prior to PHP 5.2 the `__toString` method was only "magically" called in certain circumstances (e.g. `echo()` and `print()`).  So if you are currently using `__toString()` in a "magical" way outside of direct output functions it will not work as expected.

[Source](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-5077):

> It is worth noting that before PHP
>   5.2.0 the `__toString` method was only called when it was directly combined
>   with `echo()` or `print()`. Since PHP
>   5.2.0, it is called in any string context (e.g. in `printf()` with `%s`
>   modifier) but not in other types
>   contexts (e.g. with `%d` modifier).
>   Since PHP 5.2.0, converting objects
>   without `__toString` method to string
>   would cause `E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR`.

Comment: I realized that some outputs were via echo and some were as returned values.

And now I've contacted the support guys to update php5.

Thanks

Comment: Not a problem - make sure its PHP 5.2 as that is the cutoff.

Answer (score 1):

Some host companies (like 1and1) run both PHP 4.x and 5.x and default to 4.x. You may need to have an .htaccess file that ensures you are using the correct version of PHP.

Also, the magic __toString() is slightly different from version 5.2+ according to the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php):

> It is worth noting that before PHP 5.2.0 the __toString  method was only called when it was directly combined with echo() or print(). Since PHP 5.2.0, it is called in any string context (e.g. in printf() with %s modifier) but not in other types contexts (e.g. with %d modifier). Since PHP 5.2.0, converting objects without __toString  method to string would cause E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR.

So, it may depend on how you are calling the output.